# Android Service and ResultReceiver

Tags: java, android, service

What I'm trying to achieve is to start a service that can return result to component that start this service.

In android there are two type of services: "Started" and "Bounded", my type of service is "Started", I'am starting it from Activity class via startService(...) method.

During that, I have added my custom ResultReceiver to start an intent via putExtra("rec", mMyReceiver). Communication works well but I have a question about how it is working under the hood:

1) If my service is started and I pass ResultReceiver via starting Intent then my service is "Started" or "Bounded"?

I have not implemented onBind(...) method in my service, only onStartCommand(...) method, but in documentation about [ResultReciever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html):

> Note: the implementation underneath is just a simple wrapper around a Binder that is used to perform the communication.

Please, don't answer: "use BroadcastReciever and don't bother about it" :)

Comment: the service is "bound" when you call `bindService` (in this case you have to return a `Binder` from `onBind` method) and "started" when you call `startService`

Comment: Yes, that is true. Byt as I said ResultReciever is a wrapped of a Binder class, so Service has a reference to communication channel via this Binder, so it is a bit misleading. That is why I have asked this question.

Comment: it is really not important how you pass a `Binder`: you can do that in extras as well, it is not used very often as there is not a method `Intent#putBinder` so you have to wrap your `Binder` in some custom `Parcelable` class or use `Bundle#putBinder`

Comment: You get off the track, the question is how service react when it is started and has a ResultReciever object, not how to pass it with Intent/Bundle.